# How to add a calculated value to an array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Product option that I calculate a weighted score for in Rails.

I'd like to return an array that adds the calculated product score to the array. I tried:

```
products.inject {|p| p.exponential_discount_score(0.01) }
```

But got:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `exponential_discount_score' for 246.86645269006013:Float
    from (irb):39:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):39:in `each'
    from (irb):39:in `inject'
    from (irb):39
    from /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.1rc4/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.1rc4/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.1rc4/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I thought `inject` would work, but I guess I'm doing something wrong? I also tried `.collect` but couldn't write the block correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the method you call to calculate score doesn't exist.

When you've created it, you can call something like :

```
products.collect {|p| p.exponential_discount_score(0.01) }.inject(:+)
```